# Modem Manager (mmcli): how to answering the calls from the terminal?

Tags: usb-modem, modem, mobile-broadband, modem-manager

I can confirm incoming calls by continuously listening for events with mmcli monitor, but how do I answer (or at least listen for) incoming calls from the modem manager?

I tried calling from my phone to my usb dongle (zte mf-190) and accepted successfully (with `mmcli -o <index> --accept`), but I couldn't hear anything, even though on my phone's side, the call timer had counted more than 10 seconds.

ps: btw, the mobile manager on ubuntu is really limited, and doesn't have many support tools, especially the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, at first, I'll need to identify VoUSB tty device that create when I plugged the dongle to my computer.

A simple to know is:

> `ls -alh /dev/ttyUSB*` it must be shown as 4 tty devices
> `mmcli -L` and `mmcli -m <device_id>`, the port that was not be used by Modem Manager is the VoUSB port.

Next, you just need read the audio stream appears when you're placing or taking a call on `/dev/ttyUSB<x>`.
Because it's encoding with u-law (8000 Hz, 8-bits per sample, mono, 64k), you'll need a tool to handle that.
I'm using `sox` (SOund eXchange) to play the stream above.

Just use: `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB<x> |  play -t raw -r 8000 -c 1 -e u-law -`